# How can I set up Soot when using it as a library?

Tags: java, soot

I want to use Soot library to build an SSA from *.java file. But all the examples I found use Soot as standalone tool, not library. Can anyone give me example hot to do it in program?

For a start I am just trying to load my class from the source file and print it (TestClass.class is in the directory `A/home/abdullin/workspace/test`):

```
import soot.G
import soot.Scene
import soot.options.Options

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    G.reset();
    Options.v().set_whole_program(true)
    Scene.v().loadBasicClasses()

    Scene.v().sootClassPath = "${Scene.v().defaultClassPath()}:/home/abdullin/workspace/test"

    val sc = Scene.v().getSootClass("TestClass")
    Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses()
    sc.setApplicationClass()

    println(sc.name)
    sc.methods.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

But when I run this, I get runtime exception `Aborting: can't find classfile TestClass`. If I change `Scene.v().getSootClass("TestClass")` to `Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("TestClass")` as they do in some of their tutorials, soot finds my class, but it is not complete. It prints me signatures of class methods, but can't find their bodies, `activeBody` field is null.

```
TestClass
<TestClass: void <init>()>
<TestClass: void main(java.lang.String[])>
<TestClass: void f1()>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this post (https://o2lab.github.io/710/p/a1.html). But if you try to analyze a jar file, you should unzip it and get a set of class files. Then you should add your classes directory into the soot_class_path.

Demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //spotbugs -- testing
    String classesDir = "D:\\wkspace\\seed8\\dir\\spotbugs";
    String mainClass = "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI";

    //set classpath
    String jreDir = System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\lib\\jce.jar";
    String jceDir = System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\lib\\rt.jar";
    String path = jreDir + File.pathSeparator + jceDir + File.pathSeparator + classesDir;
    Scene.v().setSootClassPath(path);

    //add an intra-procedural analysis phase to Soot
    TestCallGraphSootJar_3 analysis = new TestCallGraphSootJar_3();
    PackManager.v().getPack("wjtp").add(new Transform("wjtp.TestSootCallGraph", analysis));

    excludeJDKLibrary();

    Options.v().set_process_dir(Arrays.asList(classesDir));
    Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
    //Options.v().set_app(true);

    SootClass appClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(mainClass);
    Scene.v().setMainClass(appClass);
    Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();

    //enableCHACallGraph();
    enableSparkCallGraph();

    PackManager.v().runPacks();
}
```

If you replace

```
SootClass appclass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(mainclass);
Scene.v().setMainClass(appclass);
Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
```

by

```
Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
SootClass appclass = Scene.v().getSootClass(mainclass);
Scene.v().setMainClass(appclass);
```

, the program also works.

Comment: What does your `excludeJDKLibrary()` function do?

Comment: @shoaloak, exclude JDK classes by 'Options.v().set_exclude(xxx)'

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that the Soot jar is in the classpath.

Then, set up Soot using the classes [`soot.G`](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/jdoc/index.html?soot/G.html) and [`soot.options.Options`](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/jdoc/index.html?soot/options/Options.html) (`G.reset()` and `Options.v().parse()` are methods of interest, also see [command line options](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/options/soot_options.htm)).

Using [`soot.Scene.v().setSootClassPath()` and similar](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/jdoc/index.html?soot/Scene.html) you can tell Soot where to find the class files of the code you want to analyze.

You can then use `Scene.v().getSootClass()` to obtain SootClass objects. Make sure that Soot loads all classes after setting the class you want to analyze as main class:

```
mySootClass.setApplicationClass();
Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
```

After this, you can use Soot to obtain various types of graphs and run you analyses, as described in the [Survivor's guide](http://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/sootsurvivorsguide.pdf)

Comment: @Caphalopod I tried to do as you wrote, but I still can't load my class properly. I edited the question and showed what I tried to do.

Comment: @kivi You have to call `setApplicationClass` *before* `loadNecessaryClasses`

Comment: @kivi and you need to enable the creation of method bodies in the options, eg `Options.v().parse(new String[]{"-keep-line-number", "-p", "jb", "use-original-names:true"});`